# How to run external, downloaded yet not installed apps on Android?

Tags: android, plugins, installation, apk

I am just curious :

Some apps , usually for developers, allow to download other sample apps and execute the sample  apps without installing them.

An example for such an app is the cool "[DevAppsDirect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inappsquared.devappsdirect)" app (highly recommend it BTW) .

My question is :

How do such apps work?

I mean , do they download the APK ? How do they skip the installation phase and somehow run the downloaded apps ? Do they somehow merge with the downloaded content? Is it like a plugin?

Such a thing could be useful for apps that require plugins and extensions, and maybe other ideas that I can't think about.

i also wonder how do other apps use a plugins mechanism. many apps allow to download other  plugins-apps via the play store. do they somehow run some code in the other apk files? can they even reach the other apk files ? is there a way to tell android which apps can access my apk file ?

Comment: did you get any clear findings on this question ? any further investigation?

Comment: @VishalVyas only clues. if you wish, you can contact DevAppDirect and ask them for an SDK. maybe they will accept.

Comment: @androiddeveloper did you find the way to do it ?

Comment: @ShashankSrivastava No. I was just interested in this, and it was a long time ago. Sorry. Could still be interesting to know how to do it well.

Answer (score 8):

You can use Android's class loaders (in this particular case probably the PathClassLoader) to dynamically load classes at runtime without installing them.

Take a look at e.g. https://github.com/Rookery/AndroidDynamicLoader to see how this can be implemented.

Plugin apk's might not even need something that complicated but can just communicate via Intents sent to exported activities and posted back results. You can use PackageManager (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) to query for which intents activities are registered.

Comment: this looks really promising , but can you please show some sample code? for example, suppose i have downloaded an apk file to the internal/external storage, what should i do next in order to launch the app within it?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: "suppose i have downloaded an apk file to the internal/external storage, what should i do next in order to launch the app within it?" -- that is not possible.

Comment: @CommonsWare is correct. The PackageManager doesn't know about your sideloaded classes so it can't launch them.

According to DevAppsDirect their "technology creates a simulated Android environment within the DevAppsDirect app.". I'm assuming this means they're somehow manually calling lifecycle functions (onCreate, etc.) instead of relying on Android launching the app

Comment: no, i've investigated it. according to the content of their private app storage, they download an apk and get a dex file . because i can see the task is a new one on the android device, it is somehow running as a different app. it's not installed, but it runs somehow. i also think it shares the same folders as the app itself.

Comment: The DevAppsDirect developer is awesome, his application is also awesome, but he's also trying to sound like he's using some kind of secret mysterious sauce. He is able to repackage the apps with the same base application package name, the same same SharedUserId, with the same permissions of his launching application, and he has to sign the apps with the same developer key each time. This is only possible if you have access to the source code in the first place, like open source apps, or apps all published from the same company that trusts you enough with their source code.

Answer (score 6):

i've talked with the developer of the devAppsDirect (website [here](http://www.inappsquared.com/)) , and here's what he wrote:

> The technology behind DevAppsDirect is called inAppSquared
>   (www.inAppSquared.com) .  In a nutshell inAppSquared allows you to
>   turn an Android app into a plugin. This is done using only the
>   publicly available Android API, no crazy hacking involved.
>
> I did this by creating a new new mobile platform the same way Xamarin
>   and Titanium are mobile platforms. The difference is inAppSquared has
>   the same API as the Android API and once an app is ported to
>   inAppSquared it can be run without being installed.
>
> There are lots of possibilities for this technology. You mentioned
>   plugins and extensions, but it could also be used for App Discovery,
>   advertising, subscription services, A/B testing, bug fixing and much
>   more.

Answer (score 2):

Very Interesting! I think this is doable, thou haven't tried it myself.

- If you have an apk in your server, you could download it from your app
- Now you can use zip utility to unzip into your own applicaiton private memory
- Parse the Manifest file to determine the main activity
- Next you can use `ClassLoader` or `DexClassLoader` to dynamically loader the activity.

I believe this is what goes on in DevAppsDirect

Comment: how do you do the last 2 steps (parse the manifest and using the loaders) ? i don't even think the manifest is in a readable format... even after this, how do you use the loaders?

Comment: There are lot of utilities which will extract the apk and you can view the Manifest file completely. For Example dex2Jar, apktool etc. You could use the jar in the application itself. 


and load the dex file, File file = new File("/data/data/com.android.myapp/otherapp/classes.dex"); 
 DexFile  appDexFile = new DexFile(file);

Comment: have you tried this solution on the android platform itself? did it work?

Comment: from step 2 onwards it involves integrating an un-dex utility. I know you can run a Java program from Android (as far as Android supports those libraries), it might worth going to this path. The result of the undex operation is another jar file.

Comment: Yea, the challenge is not un-dex here, it is pretty much doable. And classloader thing is simple i guess.

             File dir1 = getDir("dex", 0);
             DexClassLoader classLoader = new DexClassLoader(dexpath, dir1.getAbsolutePath(), null, getClass().getClassLoader());
            Class<Object> myClass = (Class<Object>)    Class.forName("com.myapp.MainClass");
            Object myInstance  = myClass.newInstance();
            Method myMethod = myClass.getMethod("onCreate");
            doSomething.invoke(myInstance)

Answer (score 1):

You should try using **[Manifest Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.susatthi.ManifestViewer&hl=en)** to check out the AndroidManifest.xml of DevAppsDirect. Sadly the app doesn't have an option to export the manifest. From a cursory glance, I don't think he's actually installing the apps shown in the list. You should probably have a look.

Comment: he doesn't and i've written that he doesn't install the app. somehow he extracts what is needed and then launches it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems DevAppsDirect uses a part of the Android Open Source Project called the "Launcher", my guess is that they took that part of the OS and tweaked it so they could include it inside their own App to launch compiled APKs from the libraries as a Demo.

Launcher is in charge of the Home screen of the phone, launching other Apps, hosting widgets, etc.

You can get a copy of the Android Open Source Project here: http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html and take a look at the com.android.launcher package.

Comment: cool, but is there any library that has done it? this is the very first step, and it's very hard to understand such a huge code and take only what is needed.

Comment: Well... precisely that is the value of the DevAppsDirect App... I don't think they used an existing library that did that, they probably tweaked it themselves, you may have to figure it out yourself by browsing the Launcher's code and by trial and error... You could also take a look at Cyanogenmod, they have also hacked the Launcher and all of their code is in github (https://github.com/CyanogenMod).