# How to launch a apk without installing it first?

Tags: android, android-activity, installation, apk

I am developing an app which needs to act like a container of mini games. Each mini game is in its own apk. The app needs to be able to download the APK, and launch it, without having to install it first. Downloading the APK is solved, but my question is:

How to launch the APK without installing it first?

It doesn't have to be in the same process, the mini games just need to be launched.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059752/how-to-run-external-downloaded-yet-not-installed-apps-on-android) but there doesn't seem to be a definitive answer. I know it is possible to [launch an activity from another APK](http://blog.pentests.pl/2015/02/android-dynamic-activities.html) but there is no solution on loading the resources that inevitably accompany a game.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/113387/how-to-run-an-apk-without-installing-it-on-the-device-with-adb

Comment: This [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inappsquared.devappsdirect) seems to be doing it.

Comment: They mention an sdk that has to be used on their site, but that link is broken. http://www.inappsquared.com/devappsdirect.html. Afaik, apk has to be installed on disc, but if you can prove it's not needed pls do post it, would be a major security flaw :-)

Comment: I am not sure what the app does, but it seems able to download another app and execute it as a new app, without installing first. Works only on android 4.x, so if you have a android smartphone with that version, you can give it a whirl.